# Bayesian updating in JAGS - data not reaching posterior distribution

Tags: bayesian, survival, logit, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

I am trying to model the survival of a bird species as the function of a habitat variable, using JAGS run with the R package R2jags.  When I leave the habitat variable out, I get believable estimates for the survival parameters (phiWithin and phiAmong).  Here is that model:

```
model{

for(i in 1:nBirds) {
    z[i, first[i]] ~ dbern(1)
    for(t in (first[i] + 1) : last[i]) {  
    logit(phi[i,t]) <- mu*season[t-1,1] + mu2*season[t-1,2]    
    phiz[i, t] <- phi[i, t] * z[i, t-1]
        z[i, t] ~ dbern(phiz[i, t])
        p[i, t] <- pNorm
        pz[i, t] <- p[i, t] * z[i, t]
        y[i, t] ~ dbern(pz[i, t])
        }
    }

phiWithin ~ dunif(0.5,1)
mu <- log(phiWithin/(1-phiWithin))
phiAmong ~ dunif(0,1)
mu2 <-log(phiAmong/(1-phiAmong))

pNorm ~ dunif(0, 1)
}
```

When I add the habitat variable the posterior distributions of the survival parameters (phiWithin and phiAmong) are not updated, and closely mimic their prior distributions (e.g., dunif[0,1]).  I've tried to give really informative prior distributions, but no luck.  The covariate values are not large, they range from 5 to 21, so I haven't tried to scale them.

Here is that model:

```
model{

for(i in 1:nBirds) {
    z[i, first[i]] ~ dbern(1)
    for(t in (first[i] + 1) : last[i]) {  
    logit(phi[i,t]) <- mu*season[t-1,1] + beta*x[i] + mu2*season[t-1,2]    
    phiz[i, t] <- phi[i, t] * z[i, t-1]
        z[i, t] ~ dbern(phiz[i, t])
        p[i, t] <- pNorm
        pz[i, t] <- p[i, t] * z[i, t]
        y[i, t] ~ dbern(pz[i, t])
        }
    }

phiWithin ~ dunif(0.5,1)
mu <- log(phiWithin/(1-phiWithin))
phiAmong ~ dunif(0,1)
mu2 <-log(phiAmong/(1-phiAmong))

beta ~ dnorm(0,0.001)I(-10,10)      # prior for covariate

pNorm ~ dunif(0.3, 0.6)
}
```

Why are the posterior distributions not updating?

In Kery and Schaub's 'Bayesian Population Analysis Using WinBUGS: A Hierarchical Perspective', in 'Appendix 1: A List of WinBUGS Tricks', #14: "We have sometimes experienced problems when using WinBUGS' own logit function, for instance, with achieving convergence."  They go on to suggest explicitly specifying the logit transformation instead.

Perhaps JAGS has similar problems with the logit function?

Any clarity greatly apprectiated.

Comment: It is hard to answer or comment your question since it lacks a reproducible example. This can happen for a number of reasons, starting from bugs in WinBUGS (btw, it is pretty old and rather not developed software), model misspecification, problems with your data and a number of different reasons. The easy thing to check is just to run this model in JAGS, or Stan instead and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Tim.  Thanks for your note.  I am running the model in JAGS, not WinBUGS.  Perhaps I should try WinBUGS.  The first model shown runs fine, yet the second, using the same data and adding a covariate, does not.  I can try to include a reproducible example later, but I assume that the problem is in my model specification, shown above.  Or, with JAGS logit function?